# How to run a script when a directory is accessed?

Tags: scripting, mount, events

I want a device mounted to a mountpoint only when it is needed, when it is accessed (for the first time). How to run a script when a folder is accessed in Linux (or Ubuntu)? Please note that the device is an encrypted container and the script will ask the user for a password before it mounts.

Comment: Mounting a directory on first use is called [automounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automounter). Don't try to run a script when the directory is accessed: that wouldn't work, because you'd mount the directory after the application has already opened it and found it empty. An automounter works differently: it's always running, and the first access to the directory blocks until the mounting is done. Asking for a password from an automounter is not so easy. What encryption mechanism is it?

Comment: Presently my mount script is similar to this: 
password=$(kdialog --password 'Enter your passphrase' --title='Container passphrase')
echo -n $password|sudo /sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen $CONTAINER $MOUNT
sudo mount /dev/mapper/$MOUNT ~/$MOUNT

I think that automount would not make much sense here because the container file is not on a removible device and simply sits on my harddisk.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Asking for a passphrase, should not be too hard, if you are running in a windowing-system. Use a popup (OS/2 Warp did this type of file access intercept buitifuly).